# How to create a transparent demo on Android?

Tags: java, android, transparent, demo

I'm try to make a transparent activity in my Android application.

This is an example picture:

[image]

Does anyone know a library that can do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes like this:

```XML
<activity android:name=".usual.activity.Declaration"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

This should help you.