# Android information bubble below button

Tags: android

I noticed that when you first time run clock app in android you get small info bubble below the "plus" icon with the information what that button is for. I am wondering how can i achieve something similar to let the users know in the first run what apps' buttons are for.

Any idea how i can achieve something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a transparent demo on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616864/how-to-create-a-transparent-demo-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean to say ToolTip text to show..for what the button is to be used..or what its purpose..
if so this link can help you out

[Android PopupWindow with Tooltip Arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow)

Comment: Android PopupWindow with Tooltip Arrow seems to be it, however since core "clock" application uses that i would say it should be part of android api libraries but I guess it is not..and i need to use external one. Toast looks differently plus if I put it in 0,0 how that would work with different screen sizes.

Comment: if you are using tootlip..then they use nine patch images..which will adjust acc to screen sizes and text

Comment: I decided to try out showcaseview https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView but I will accept your answer because it helped me to get there :) - Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I created a library based on PopupWindow.

https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

You can display an info bubble with a simple line of code :

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your message.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You'll need to import: `android.widget.Toast;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a toast for this. In order to set the position of the toast you can use the setGravity method as well.

Toast : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

For example:

Toast.makeText(getActivity, "Some text", TOAST.LENTH_SHORT).show();
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);